# Oracle connection suddenly refused on windows 8

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, connectivity

I am having all kinds of connection issues with sql developer all of a sudden. It was working till yesterday and stopped working on windows 8 machine.

I am still able to connect via command prompt.

I exclusively opened the port 1521 thats been configured for listener.

Also opened all ports for local programs.

Added TNS_ADMIN to register keys.

But still no luck

Heres my `listener.ora`:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
(GLOBAL_DBNAME=orcl)
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\rani\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\rani\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\app\rani
```

- `tnsnames.ora` content:

```
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

Everything fine from command prompt:

```
    Show parameter service_name;

    NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- -----------------
service_names                        string      orcl


    C:\Users\rani>lsnrctl services LISTENER

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 11-DEC-2014 23:44
:51

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
```

I think I have done everything I possibly can, but I'm still not able to conenct my sqlplus developer. I keep getting: `Network adapter could not establish connection`.

sqlnet log details:

```
Fatal NI connect error 12505, connecting to:
 (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\app\rani\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\emagent.exe)(HOST=PICKLE)(USER=SYSTEM))))

  VERSION INFORMATION:
    TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
    Windows NT TCP/IP NT Protocol Adapter for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
  Time: 11-DEC-2014 23:09:10
  Tracing to file: C:\app\rani\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\trace\sqlnet.trc
  Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12564
    TNS-12564: TNS:connection refused
    ns secondary err code: 0
    nt main err code: 0
    nt secondary err code: 0
    nt OS err code: 0
```

fyi: my computer name is PICKLE which should be same as localhost.

```
listener details:
    C:\Users\rani>lsnrctl services LISTENER

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 12-DEC-2014 00:14
:15

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
The command completed successfully

    C:\Users\rani>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 12-DEC-2014 00:14
:39

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Produ
ction
Start Date                12-DEC-2014 00:13:54
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 45 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   C:\app\rani\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\list
ener.ora
Listener Log File         c:\app\rani\diag\tnslsnr\pickle\listener\alert\log.xml

Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Any help, I am thinking the sql developer is not ready for windows 8 may be

Answer (score 2):

Solved! The issue was `LOCAL_LISTENER` was not set to `orcl`.
So

```
SQL> alter system register;

SQL> alter system set LOCAL_LISTENER='(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))' scope=both;
```

did the trick!

Comment: thanks, after so many hard work for finding solution. this resolved my issues. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a service called 'orcl' when you do a

```
lsnrctl status
```

But at the moment you don't. Or inversely try to change your tnsname.ora (SERVICE_NAME = orcl) to 'CLRExtProc'.